# Running a long task IHosted service at the same time and can manually turned on and off

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, backgroundworker, asp.net-core-hosted-services

hi i am having a problem in running a long task for my background service using the IHostedService at first it really work fine but in the long run the background service suddenly stopped with this thread exited code:

```
The thread 10824 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 12340 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 9324 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 11168 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 11616 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 9792 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

i register my background service as

```
//Register Background 
serviceCollection.AddSingleton<CoinPairBackgroundService>
serviceCollection.AddSingleton<SaveFakePersonBackgroundService>();
serviceCollection.AddSingleton<LeaderboardMinutesBackgroundService>();
serviceCollection.AddSingleton<LeaderboardHoursBackgroundService>();

serviceCollection.AddSingleton<IHostedService, CoinPairBackgroundService>();
serviceCollection.AddSingleton<IHostedService, SaveFakePersonBackgroundService>();
serviceCollection.AddSingleton<IHostedService, LeaderboardMinutesBackgroundService>();
serviceCollection.AddSingleton<IHostedService, LeaderboardHoursBackgroundService>();
```

because in the future i want to manually turned on and off my background services with use of

```
IServiceProvider provider = _serviceProvider.GetService<MyBackgroundServiceHere>();
provider.StartAsync();
provider.StopAsync
```

and this was my code in my background services StartAsync

```
    public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _logger.LogDebug("Leaderboard minute ranking updates is starting");
        Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                _logger.LogDebug("Leaderboard minute ranking updates  is dequeueing");
                await DequeueRandomCustomers();

                _logger.LogDebug("Leaderboard minute ranking updates  is enqueueing");
                await EnqueueRandomCustomers();

                _logger.LogDebug("Leaderboard minute ranking updates  thread is now sleeping");
                //sleep for 1 minute
                await Task.Delay(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10));
            }
        });
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
```

I am confuse if there are some problems with registering my background service because i see my background service starts but in the long run it suddenly stopped i already get rid of those Thread.Sleep() in my background services hope you can help thanks in advance.

Comment: Why you are registering twice? And why you are not using `AddHostedService`?

Comment: @FarhadJabiyev its because i cannot get the IHostedService without registering first the concrete class that implements IHostedService as you can see i am using the StartAsync() and StopAsync() of IHostedService to manually turned on and off my BackgroundServices

Comment: It is not good to decide which services to run while configuring services. Instead of that, just create additional configs inside `appsettings.json` and check the value inside `StartAsync`. If it is turned off, then just return completed result.

Comment: @FarhadJabiyev so that means i will be having a variable in my appsettings.json that changed its value for turning on and off my background services? what if i have more than 1 background services that means i will be having too many variables in my appsettings.json?

Comment: It is the reason for existence of appsettings

Comment: @FarhadJabiyev yes but how about to start again my background service? for instance i have my background service 1 turned on in start and then the background service 1 check my appsettings.json then it will check that the configuration is turned off, how can i turned it on again? if i cannot access the StartAsync() anymore because if the StartAsync() return Task.Completed() it will not run again right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of managing hosted services lifetime in a such weird way, you can set configuration for services inside `appsettings.json`, configure it as `reloadOnChange: true`, and use `IOptionsMonitor<>` to access current values from `appsettings.json`. And use that settings as a cancellation for started task inside hosted service's `StartAsync` method. And you need to listen to `OnChange` event of `IOptionsMonitor<>` for restarting services.

`appsettings.json`:

```
 "HostedService": {
    "RunService1": true
  }
```

Register that options so:

```
public class HostedServiceConfig
{
     public bool RunService1 { get; set; }
}

services.Configure<HostedServiceConfig>(Configuration.GetSection("HostedService"));
```

And then create `HostedService1` and register with the help of the `AddHostedService`:

```
 services.AddHostedService<HostedService1>();
```

And here is the example for `StartAsync`:

```
  public class HostedService1 : IHostedService
  {
        private readonly IOptionsMonitor<HostedServiceConfig> _options;
        private CancellationToken _cancellationToken;

        public HostedService1(IOptionsMonitor<HostedServiceConfig> options)
        {
            _options = options;

             // Or listen to changes and re-run all services from one place inside `Configure` method of `Startup`
            _options.OnChange(async o =>
            {
                if (o.RunService1)
                {
                    await StartAsync(_cancellationToken);
                }
            });
        }

        public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            if(_cancellationToken == null) 
            {
                 _cancellationToken = cancellationToken;
            }

            Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                while (!_cancellationToken .IsCancellationRequested || !_options.CurrentValue.RunService1)
                {
                     ....
                }
            });

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        ...
   }
```

In case of any changes inside `appSettings.json`, you `_options.CurrentValue.RunService1` will be reloaded automatically.

Comment: yes but my question is how i can restart my background service when it breaks the loop inside StartAsync()? is there any way that i can call this HostedService1 to run again?

Comment: @JamesTubiano Oh got it, you need to restart it automatically? Or manually from `appsettings` is ok?

Comment: i want to restart it manually is there any way that i can start and stopped that HostedService1 manually using appsettings?